# Setting root view controller is not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, rootviewcontroller

My code is

```
#import "AppDelegate"
```

in viewDidLoad

```
self.delegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

After getting the response

```
//If server response is success make HomeViewController as Root VC
if ([[[_response objectForKey:@"Response"] objectForKey:@"status"]  isEqualToString:@"SUCCESS"]) {

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

//Make root view controller
UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]; //My storyboard name is Main.storyboard
HomeViewController * hvc = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HVC"];
self.delegate.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:hvc];
[self.delegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];

});
}
```

But it's not working...

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What is the output you are getting?

Comment: What is not working fo you ? , Are you sure about your all the  identifier  are correct ?

Comment: I want to set my home page is root VC. When I reopen my app it's getting login page not Home page

Comment: @Prashant Tukadiya yes, all id's are correct and it's moving from login page to home page successfully. After reopen my app its opening agin login page not home page, but I made home page is root page

Comment: @Marking , Once you logged in. Set a boolean variable to UserDefault. now in appDelegate check if bool variable isn't nil and true then directly set HomeViewController from there. no need to go to login view controller

Comment: @  Prashant Tukadiya can you send code for me...

Comment: @Marking course pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to implement is auto login functionality (if user already logged in then no need for login page).
What you are doing is correct but you also need to managed that thing from `AppDelegate` too.
You need to add one line to code after setting root view controller is

```
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isUserLoggedIn"]; 
        // PUT this line after  [self.delegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

You can create method in AppDelegate which monitor a boolean variable from UserDefault. and navigate to vc1 -> vc2

Put it in Appdelegate and call it from `didFinishLuanchWithOptions`

```
- (void) checkLoginStatusAndProceed {
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isUserLoggedIn"] && [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isUserLoggedIn"] == YES) {
        // Navigate to HomeViewController
        //Make root view controller
        UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]; //My storyboard name is Main.storyboard
        HomeViewController * hvc = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HVC"];
        self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:hvc];
       [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }

}
```

Comment: @  Prashant Tukadiya I think this will help for me, please wait I will update my code

Comment: @Marking Happy to help :)

Comment: @ Prashant Tukadiya  Thank you

Comment: You should not name your method as checkUserAlreadyLoggedIn because it's not checking if the user is logged in or not.I would suggest using 'checkLoginStatusAndProceed' or something similar.

Comment: @VishalSonawane Thanks for feedback but it does check user login status by `isUserLoggedIn` from userdefault

Comment: @PrashantTukadiyaYes it is checking, but that's not the only task in that method. The method is also transferring the control to another VC.It's just a suggestion though.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Welcome brother :)

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT Code**
Implement Two methods in Appdelegate Class like this :-

```
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
        var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

            application.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

            return true
        }
        func showTabBar()  {

            let tabBarContoller = UIStoryboard(name: OTPStoryBoards.Booking, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: OTPViewControllers.TabBarController) as! UITabBarController
            self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarContoller
        }

        func showLogin()  {
            let loginVC = UIStoryboard(name: OTPStoryBoards.Authentication, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: OTPViewControllers.LoginVC) as! OTPLoginViewController
            let navigationControler = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginVC)
            self.window?.rootViewController = navigationControler
        }
}
```

And whenever you want to change root call these methods

```
let APP_DELEGATE    = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

  APP_DELEGATE.showLogin() or APP_DELEGATE.showTabBar()
```

Comment: Not in app delegate, I want from vc1 to vc1, means login page to home page.

Comment: @Marking You can call the method from whichever view controller you want. I have Updated answer please check

Answer (score 1):

In your `LoginViewController` you need to keep track of the user login status that user is successfully logged in. For that you can store a `bool` var in UserDefaults like...

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

So when ever app is relaunched then you need to check that user is already logged in or not....and based on that you can show desired screen...

```
if let isLoggedIn = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn") as? Bool, isLoggedIn == true {

   //Make root view controller
   UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]; 
   HomeViewController * hvc = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HVC"];
   self.delegate.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:hvc];

} else {
    //show login view controller as user is not yet logged in
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirements, you need to maintain a flag may be in `UserDefaults`.

**NOTE: Its just pseudo code, as I am not at my desk with laptop**

**Follow steps like this:**

1. Create user defaults object and save flag e.g `isFirstLaunch = false`
2. After setting your HomeVC as root, change this flag to true .
3. In AppDelegate in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, check for this flag again like

   if UserDefaults.standard.bool(for:"isFirstLaunch"){
          //Show Login
       }else{
          //Show Home
       }